# Playing PCm data in audiotrack

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, jlayer

I decoded the mp3 using jLayer lib when i tried to play the pcm data through audiotrack is giving lot of audio distortion.

my decoder code:

```
public static void decode(String path, int startMs, int maxMs) 
              throws IOException {
              ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

              float totalMs = 0;
              boolean seeking = true;

              File file = new File(path);
              System.out.println("the data "+path);
              InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 8 * 1024);
              try {
                Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(inputStream);
                Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

                boolean done = false;  
                while (! done) {
                  javazoom.jl.decoder.Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
                  if (frameHeader == null) {
                    done = true;      
                  } else {
                    totalMs += frameHeader.ms_per_frame();

                    if (totalMs >= startMs) {   
                      seeking = false;
                    }  

                    if (! seeking) {
                      SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);

                      if (output.getSampleFrequency() != 44100
                          || output.getChannelCount() != 2) {
                       // throw new com.mindtherobot.libs.mpg.DecoderException("mono or non-44100 MP3 not supported");
                      }

                      short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
                      byte[] bs;
                      int index=0;
                      ByteBuffer buffer;
                      buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2*pcm.length);

                      for (short s : pcm) {     
//                      outStream.write(s & 0xff);      
//                      outStream.write((s >> 8 ) & 0xff);   


                        buffer.putShort(s);



                      }      

                      byte[] dataaudio = buffer.array();

                      //return buffer.array();






                      track.write(dataaudio, 0, dataaudio.length);

                    }   

                    if (totalMs >= (startMs + maxMs)) {
                      done = true;
                    }
                  }
                  bitstream.closeFrame();
                }

                //return outStream.toByteArray();
              } catch (BitstreamException e) {
                throw new IOException("Bitstream error: " + e);
              } catch (DecoderException e) {  
                Log.w("data", "Decoder error", e);
                ;
              } finally {
               // IOUtils.safeClose(inputStream);     
              }
            }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using MediaPlayer? It will automatically decode your audio file and play it back for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually i want to stream data to other device...

Comment: I see... maybe you should give a native MP3 decoder library a try. It will be faster than a decoder written in Java and maybe you'll also get rid of the audio distortion problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you don't convert your short[] to byte[], but write your short[] to the AudioTrack i.e. call track.write(pcm, 0, pcm.length) instead of track.write(dataaudio, 0, dataaudio.length).

I have been writing an audio processor for Android which uses JLayer to read MP3 files, processes the data, then outputs to AudioTrack. If I do not do any data processing, but just send the data from JLayer to the AudioTrack, it plays really well on my Nexus7.
However, when I do my processing (pitch-shift and/or time compression), I get an annoying crackle.

Strangely, when I read one frame from JLayer and send it to AudioTrack (no processing), it sounds good, but when I read two frames from JLayer and send them to AudioTrack (no processing), I get the crackle!

I've started doing some investigations outside Android (basically running the same code, but with my own implementation dummy of AudioTrack which either plays the sound on my laptop or converts to a WAV file) & the results so far are very odd.

So, if you have progressed further, I'd be interested to know how you are doing.